# The famous ERROR 1009in Flash AS3, please

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i've visited this forum and I haven't found any answer to my problem.
So, I have a project that consists in a button which calls a 360 animated shoe.

When I call the 360 directly from Frame 1 all seems to be OK, but, when I create a Scene 2 and I move all objects from scene 1 to scene 2 and in scene 1 I put a button to call Scene 2, appears the famous error 1009.

I uploaded the source code and the .fla proyect here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/63fx5na1jhg8eef/Untitled-1.fla

Please help me

Best Regards

EDIT: Sorry for post my source

That what I did:
1.- I use an old project with a movieclip called ohm_mc
2.- I copied all the elements of that project and i put all on a Scene 2
3.- In Scene 1 i put a button to call the scene 2
4.- The code of the button is:

```
stop();

boton_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,segundafuncion);


function segundafuncion (event:MouseEvent) :void {
   gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

5.- In the Scene 2 there are several objects, those objects are:
MovieClip ohm, and it instance is ohm_mc
Button girar_btn, and it instance is girar_btn

In the AS Layer in Scene 2, these lines are showing the error:

```
ohm_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
ohm_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clickHandler);
```

I see the Scene 2 and I put the object in that scene, that's because i don't understand why this error happens, additionally, before these lines i give action listeners to girar_btn and there's no problem.

Comment: You should post any relevant code here, not link to a `.fla` file. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: OK, sorry for that, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash click 'Debug' > 'Debug movie' > 'in Flash Professional'. When the 1009 error pops up you'll get a line number (and frame number as it sounds like you're using the timeline). That will make it much easier to isolate where the error is coming from. Then trace like crazy any values on that line you suspect might be null.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it, and i know where's the problem, but I don't know why it happens, te error is is Scene 2, Frame 1, Layer AS, when I call: ohm_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);

Comment: wwhen I trace ohm_mc it says it's null, but the object is in the Scene 2, Frame 1, that's why I don't know how this error happens....

Comment: Please see the project, you'll understand what i'm trying to say

Comment: I haven't looked at your source. Does your ohm_mc have a keyframe at frame 1? Is that keyframe given the instance name 'ohm_mc'? Is the scene playing and therefore, perhaps losing the instance label? If so, make sure it's sent to scene 2 and stopped. You might want to avoid using scenes; Try putting all of your content on one timeline, with timeline labels (eg gotoAndStop("sceneTwo");). Most of all I'd recommend using external AS classes and instantiating your content through variables and (for example) addChild(ohmVariableName);